# Differences between "mercy" & "grace" & "divine bounty"

Tags: word-meaning

> Consider the past. How many, both high and low, have, at all times, yearningly awaited the advent of the Manifestations of God in the sanctified persons of His chosen Ones. How often have they expected His coming, how frequently have they prayed that the breeze of **divine mercy** might blow, and the promised Beauty step forth from behind the veil of concealment, and be made manifest to all the world. And whensoever the portals of **grace** did open, and the clouds of **divine bounty** did rain upon mankind, and the light of the Unseen did shine above the horizon of celestial might, they all denied Him, and turned away from His face—the face of God Himself. Refer ye, to verify this truth, to that which hath been recorded in every sacred Book.
>
> The Kitáb-i-Íqán
>
> Author: Bahá’u’lláh

My question is about the differences between *mercy, grace,* and *divine bounty*. Can you explain these concepts in simple English?

Answer (score 3):

We might be straying from language to theology here. I think these words have an almost technical meaning in Christian theology that is a little more specific than their meaning in common use, and may not match their meaning in Baha'i -- I believe the Kitab I iqan is a Baha'i book. (And I just double-checked and Wikipedia, the holy book of the Internet, says it is, so it must be so.)

But that said, here's the Christian answer, make of it what you will:

"Bounty" is an easy one. That simply means "lots of good things". You can speak of bounty without reference to any religion, like "The thieves were surprised at the bounty they found when they robbed a seemingly-middle class house." "Divine bounty" means lots of good things that come from God. So you might say, "I looked at the beautiful world God created for humanity and praised him for his divine bounty."

"Mercy" means not getting something bad that you deserve. Like if you robbed a bank and the law says that the penalty is 5 years in jail, but the judge lets you off with 1 year probation, then the judge "gave you mercy" or "showed you mercy". In Christianity, we say that all people are sinners and deserve to spend eternity in Hell, but God gives us a way out of that punishment, and so shows us mercy.

"Grace" is when you get something good that you don't deserve. A very mundane use of this is in loan payments. Banks often say that the payment is due on, say, the first of the month, but that they will give you a "grace period" of ten days (or whatever number) before they charge you a late fee. In Christian theology, we say that no one deserves to spend eternity in Paradise, no one is good enough to merit that, but God gives us this as an act of grace.

Comment: Adding on to that, Grace also refers to the power of God.

Comment: Basically if I could give a conclusion to this answer, every religion and situation has a different definition of these words, and sometimes in literature are used excessively, even incorrectly by native english speakers due to the flexibility of interpretation of these words.